# Google Pagespeed recommends <script> as direct child element of <html> - valid HTML?

Tags: html, google-pagespeed

Following Google Pagespeed's recommendations, a colleague just put the `<script>` tags right between the `</body>` and `</html>` closing tags. My immediated assumption was that `<html>` allows only for `<head>` and `<body>` as direct descendants, which I could not exactly verify in the [W3C specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/semantics.html#the-html-element):

It says:

> Content model:
>   A head element followed by a body element.

To make it clear, what Google pagespeed suggests looks somewhat like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>...</body>
  <script>...</script>
  <script>...</script>
  <script>...</script>
  <script>...</script>
</html>
```

Does anyone know better or more precisely and can provide a link to a relevant piece of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content model states it pretty clearly: the only children that an html element can legally have is a head element followed by a body element. Not a lone head element, not a lone body element, not a body followed by a head, and certainly not any *other* element. There are many contexts in which a script element may appear, but it must always be a descendant of either the head element or the body element.

Google is known for recommending that authors ignore the standards in favor of eking out every last bit of performance, especially when doing so is known not to have any adverse effects or cause any divergent browser behavior. It's up to the author whose guidelines they want to follow.

Comment: That was also my interpretation and assumption, but in contrast to you I don't see it as clearly stated as you do. Your answers on SO are usually exhausting and in most cases, very exact and precise. So I'm assuming you also have no other reference than the specs I linked?

Comment: @connexo: Fair enough. The content model is always explicit and if it doesn't mention something (e.g. script-supporting elements) then you can assume it's disallowed. Anyway, the closest other references I can give you are the definitions for head ("Contexts in which this element can be used: As the first element in an html element.") and body ("Contexts in which this element can be used: As the second element in an html element."). No other element is described in this manner as being acceptable as a child of an html element.

Comment: That was exactly what I also found when I checked the specs yesterday. I was hoping for something that states it more explicitly. Anyway, thanks for your answer which I will accept now.